# Number Guessing Game. How To Print Guessing Range?

Tags: java

This is the code I have:

```
    import java.util.*;
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean guessed = false;
        int randInt = rand.nextInt(10000) + 1;

        System.out.println("Guess my number. It's between 1 and 10,000.");

        while (!guessed) {
            int guess = 0;
            do {
                if(!scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    String notInt = scan.next();
                    System.out.printf("%s is not an integer.\n", notInt);
                }
                else
                    guess = scan.nextInt();
            }while (guess == 0);

            if(guess > randInt) {
                System.out.println(guess + " is too high.");
            }
            else if(guess < randInt) {
                System.out.println(guess + " is too low.");
            }
            else if (guess == randInt) {
                System.out.println(guess + " is the number!");
                guessed = true;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

It is the Number Guessing game where the computer generates a random number between 1 and 10,000 and the user has to guess it by cues. 
My question is how do I get console to output a new guessing range after each guess?
Let's say the user guesses 5000 and console says "5000 is too high."
After the guess I want there to be a print of the guessing range.
Since 5000 is too high I would like console to print
Guess is between 1 and 5000.
Then let's say the user guesses 400. "400 is too low."
Guess is between 400 and 5000.
What do I need to do to get the console to print a new guessing range after each guess?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize your code by doing something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     Random rand = new Random();
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int randInt = rand.nextInt(10000) + 1;
     int max=10000, min=1, counter=1;

     while(true){
         try{
             System.out.printf("Guess my number. It's between %d and %d:\n",  min, max);
             int guess = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

             if((guess>randInt && guess<=10000)){
                 System.out.println(guess + " is too high!"); 
                 max=guess;
             }
             else if(guess<randInt && guess>=1){
                 System.out.println(guess + " is too low!"); 
                 min=guess;
             }
             else if(guess==randInt){
                 System.out.println(guess + " is the number! After " + counter + " attempt");
                 break;
            } 
            counter++;   
         }
         catch(NumberFormatException e){
             System.out.println("Please Insert Only Integers!");
             continue;
         }
     }
     scan.close();
  }
}
```

**Test**

[image: test]

---

**How it works?**

- Read the entire line in every loop, and parse it, if it's invalid input, this will throw the exception, accordingly you inform the user.
- If it's a valid input, evaluate it by comparing it with the random number.
- According to the guess number, you either change the `max` or `min` values.
- This way prevents the user from going beyond the upper & lower bounds (*i.e. 1 and 10000*).
- If the guessing is correct, break the loop. So, you do not need to use extra `boolean` variable.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without break or continue statements?

Comment: @ReiKawakubo Why? Is it an assignment and the teacher told ye not to use `break` and `continue` and just to use `do... while()`?

Comment: Also, do you know how to output the number of guesses it took once you guess the number?

Comment: And no, I'm just curious.

Comment: @ReiKawakubo `break` and `continue` exist to be used and to avail from them, of course you can achieve that somehow without using them.
Answering your second question, you can just use a counter variable of type `int` and increment it every loop, finally print it out when the user guesses the number.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Can you help? Forgive me, I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: Alright I will. But it says after 0 attempts. it doesn't give me the correct attempts.

Comment: @ReiKawakubo It will only give ya this output in one of the following scenarios: either you're not incrementing `counter` properly or you could guess it after the very first attempt!.. Please copy-paste the above code to your IDE! And changing the `counter` initial value from 0 to 1 would solve the second problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two integers, upperRange, and lowerRange. Whenever the user guesses too high, upperRange is set to the user's guess. Likewise for lowerRange.

```
int upperRange;
int lowerRange;
if(guess > randInt) {
            System.out.println(guess + " is too high.");
            upperRange = guess;

} else if(guess < randInt) {
            System.out.println(guess + " is too low.");
            lowerRange = guess;
}
System.out.println("Guessing range: " + lowerRange + "-" + upperRange);
```